# this code in python 3 shows error, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'w',
           'x', 'y', 'z']
phrase = input('Write a phrase: ')
for i in range(1, 26):
    phrase = phrase.replace(alphabet[i-1], alphabet[i+12])
print(phrase)
```

I just want it to replace letters in a phrase by 13 positions, but it shows error on line 5, please help.

Comment: you are going over the end of your alphabet ...

Comment: What is the error? Do sparks fly out? Does your computer sprout wings and fly away? Does the building catch on fire? Does gravity turn off? HELP!

Comment: @adsmith That's a nice way of expressing the question haha

Comment: it shows IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: An alphabet with only 23 letters?

Comment: So if you replace all the `a` with `n` and then all the `n` with `a` etc, you'll turn "banana" to "baaaaa". Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically ROT13 if I'm not mistaken:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.encode("Hello World!", "rot_13")
'Uryyb Jbeyq!'
```

Comment: indeed it is, thanks a lot, this just made it easier :)

Answer (score 3):

When `i` is already more than `15`, `phrase[i+12]` will cause an error because `phrase[27]` doesn't exist.

You can solve the issues using a bit of calculation:

```
for i, v in enumerate(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.replace(v, alphabet[(i+12)%26])
```

Also.. You're missing `j`, `u`, and `v`..

Comment: Exactly so. May want to point out that using modulo can solve the issue of ranges you want to wrap, e.g. `phrase.replace(alphabet[i-1], alphabet[(i+12)%len(alphabet)])`

Comment: @adsmith Should be `phrase.replace(alphabet[i-1], alphabet[(i+12)%23]`, if you look closely you see that there are only `23` chars in this alphabet...

Comment: @Nabla It's stupid-proof now. That's the only code I can ever get to compile! I wonder why......;)

Comment: you can also use `string.ascii_lowercase` to help with the alphabet problem ;)

Comment: thanks for helping, im new to this so pardon my silly question

Answer (score 1):

This case only handles lowercase for now but could be updated to also handle upper case letters:

`"".join([chr((ord(i) + shift) % (ord("z")-ord("a")) + ord("a")) for i in phrase])`

where `shift` is the shift in the alphabet and `phrase` the user input.

It makes use of [ord](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) and [chr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr)

Comment: Yuck. Why not use str.translate?

Comment: @JamesMills, seriously? a generator expression would be fine.

Comment: @gnibbler Yes a generator would be better :)